# Composer dependency error acquiring microsoft/windowsazure package

Tags: php, azure, pear, composer-php

I'm having difficulty getting the PHP client libraries package for Windows Azure via Composer. The problem would appear to be around Pear dependencies the package has.

The contents of the composer.json file:

```
  {
      "require": {
          "microsoft/windowsazure": "dev-dev"
      },
      "repositories": [
          {
              "type": "pear",
              "url": "http://pear.php.net"
          }
      ]
  }
```

The output following running "composer update" reads:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Installation request for microsoft/windowsazure dev-dev -> satisfiable by microsoft/windowsazure[dev-dev].
- microsoft/windowsazure dev-dev requires pear-pear/http_request2 * -> no matching package found.
```

I've never experienced any difficulty getting this package in the past. I can provide more verbose logs on request.

Comment: Try `{
            "type": "pear",
            "url": "http://pear2.php.net"
       }`

Comment: Tried this, same result.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I recall seeing a few issues raised due to changes in how `replaces` works in regards to pear bridging.

This issue needs to be fixed upstream to have `pear-pear/*` replaced with `pear-pear.php.net/*`, but as a workaround in your root `composer.json` you can explicitly require the dependencies in order to have them discovered by the solver.

```
{
    "require": {
        "microsoft/windowsazure": "dev-dev",
        "pear-pear.php.net/http_request2": "*",
        "pear-pear.php.net/mail_mime": "*",
        "pear-pear.php.net/mail_mimedecode": "*"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "pear",
            "url": "http://pear.php.net"
        }
    ]
}
```

The above `composer.json` should work in the latest and future versions of composer.  Tested with `Composer version aa9c257f0efd1a54c93ba95282821a497bc15d75 2014-03-09 15:09:15`

Comment: Wonderful, this issue was ruining my week. Thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks. Btw, why does it asking for GitHub credentials to access some private repos?

Comment: @sarat composer needs to read the repository to get the metadata, it can't do that with private repositories unless you've set them up in a way composer doesn't need access such as private key auth.

Comment: There's a chance that this answer is no longer applicable.

Comment: I think the answer is still applicable to the problem, but the problem is likely to no longer be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

This is a composer bug, I fixed it by using an older version of composer. Your `composer.json` is fine. The version I used was:

```
Composer version 42c496752ab6ec6c45b185b70c8c39220da01b1c
```

https://github.com/composer/composer/archive/42c496752ab6ec6c45b185b70c8c39220da01b1c.zip

Comment: It's not so much a bug as it is a BC breakage introduced by a bug/security fix/implementation change.